# react-redux "s" en import afecta datos

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

tengo un problema con `react` y `redux`. 
tengo un archivo llamado **`store.js`** con el siguiente contenido:

```
import { createStore , combineReducers} from "redux"

//se importan los reducers
import results from './reducers/results';
import suggestions from './reducers/suggestions';
import currentItem from './reducers/currentItems';
import currentItems from './reducers/currentItems';



//variable principal que manejará a redux
const reducer = combineReducers({
    results,
    suggestions,
    currentItem
});

//creo el store
const store = createStore(reducer);

console.log("josejulian---",currentItems);

//exporto el módulo
export default store;
```

y sus respectivos **reducer**:

```
import { type as findCurrentItemType } from '../actions/findCurrentItems';
import items from '../../data/items';

const defaultState = [];

function reducer(state = defaultState, { type, payload }) {
    console.log("tipo de reducer: ", type);
    switch (type) {
        case findCurrentItemType: {
            console.log("SISISIS encontro");
            if (!payload) {
                return null;
            }

            console.log("SI: " , items.find(n => n.id === payload));

            return items.find(n => n.id === payload);
        }

        default:
            console.log("no encontro");
            return state;
    }
}
export default reducer;

export const type = 'findCurrentItem';

const findCurrentItem = (itemId) => ({
    type,
    payload: +itemId,
});

export default findCurrentItem;
```

La cuestión es que en el archivo **`sotre.js`** si yo formo al **reducer** principal con el `<<import currentItems>>` en vez de `<<currentItem>>` **(con una "s" al final)**:

```
//variable principal que manejará a redux
const reducer = combineReducers({
    results,
    suggestions,
    currentItems
});
```

la página no me carga el contenido, pero si lo formo con el archivo `<<currentItem>>` si carga el contenido.

¿Que tiene que ver que el `import` del archivo sea así:

```
import currentItem from './reducers/currentItems';
```

y no de esta forma

```
import currentItems from './reducers/currentItems';
```

(llamado el `import` con una **"s"** al final del nombre)

para que funcione bien mi aplicación?

**Nota**: la demás parte de la aplicación está bien configurada y funciona, sólo que ahí cuando se importa el archivo con una **"s"** y se utiliza no carga la información y cuando se realiza sin la **"s"** si funciona normalmente

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que tu archivo lo llamaras como `currentItems.js` pero al momento de exportar el reducer le colocaste `export default currentItem` nada mas. Deberías tenerlo así:  `export default currentItems`